# How convert a D array to C variadic?

Tags: d, variadic, phobos

I would like convert an array in D of the form:

```
string[] arrayStr = [ "hi, "is fun", "use D programming" ];
```

I have a C function which takes a C variadic:

```
void c_func( const char* format, ... );
```

I could do:

```
foreach(str; arrayStr)
    func( str );
```

But this seems like hacking the C variadic and I would rather convert directly to C vararg,

How can I do this?

thanks

Comment: Well, you can always use [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) to construct the call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A D array is a struct consisting of length and pointer. For instance, you can pass a D string to printf by formatting it as "%.*s".

So if you pass your array to the C function's variadic argument, it will find a long int (length) and a char[]* (ptr) in its varargs.